# Double # showing 0 on android

Tags: android, math, double

I'm embarrassed to ask this question, but after 45 minutes of not finding a solution I will resort to public humiliation.

I have a number that is being divided by another number and I'm storing that number in a double variable. The numbers are randomly generated, but debugging the app shows that both numbers are in fact being generated.

Lets just say the numbers are 476 & 733. I then take the numbers and divide them to get the percentage 476/733 = .64

I then print out the variable and it's always set to 0. I've tried using DecimalFormat and NumberFormat. No matter what I try though it always says the variable is 0. I know there is something simple that I'm missing, I just can't find it =/.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I imagine that you are trying to do something like this:

```
int x = 476;
int y = 733;
double result = x / y;     // result == 0
```

The problem here is that you are performing integer division which gives the answer 0, and then afterwards converting the result to a double. You need to convert one or both of the numbers to floating point numbers *before* dividing. Here's one way to do that:

```
int x = 476;
int y = 733;
double result = ((double)x) / y;
```

Comment: Lol you nailed it. I was using 2 ints instead of doubles. I knew it was something simple I was over looking. Thanks!

Comment: OMG. Thank you soooo much!! I was having so much trouble with this. Strange thing is, if I run the same app with 1.5, it didn't cause a problem. But running the same code in 2.2 did. Wierd, hu!!

Answer (score 0):

I presume the 2 numbers that are being divided are "double" types?

Have you used debug mode to see the result of the division?